# Android Timezone Ids are not matching with System Timezone Ids issue

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

I am working on timezones concept in Android.

I want to change the timezone of the Android tablet by taking the timezone from the App Variable in the application. I am getting the System TimeZones as the variable value i.e like

```
Dateline Standard Time
UTC-11
Samoa Standard Time
Hawaiian Standard Time
Alaskan Standard Time  
Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
Pacific Standard Time
US Mountain Standard Time
Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)
Mountain Standard Time
Central America Standard Time
Central Standard Time
Central Standard Time (Mexico)
Canada Central Standard Time
SA Pacific Standard Time
```

From Android case, I am getting Timezone Id's like

```
 Africa/Harare
 Africa/Johannesburg
 Africa/Kigali
 Africa/Lubumbashi
 Africa/Lusaka
 Africa/Maputo
 Africa/Maseru
 Africa/Mbabane
 Africa/Tripoli
 Asia/Amman
 Asia/Beirut
 Asia/Istanbul
 Asia/Jerusalem
 Asia/Nicosia
 Asia/Tel_Aviv
 CAT
 EET
 Egypt
 Etc/GMT-2
 Europe/Chisinau
 Europe/Helsinki
```

and my code is

```
 if (mCalendar != null) {
         mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     }
     else
     {               
         String[] allTimeZones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
         Arrays.sort(allTimeZones);
         for (int i = 0; i < allTimeZones.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(allTimeZones[i]);
         }  

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(String.valueOf(Jordan Standard Time));           
         mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(tz);  
         String name = tz.getID();
         System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " + name);                        
     }
```

As 'Jordan Standard Time' is variable from application is not like Timezone of tablet available Id's, Timezone is not changing.

If I replace the Timezone with 'Africa/Tripoli' manually, the timezone is replacing with this one.

My issue now is I would like to convert the system timezones to Tablet Timezone Ids and display it in Android Application.

Answer (score 0):

plz use this function that is display GMT Time display if you change timezone from you android phone.

```
public static String GetDateForGMTDate(String dateString) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-mm-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date date = null;
        try {

            date = formatter.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            Log.i("Time zone", "gettime=" + cal.getTime());
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-1 * getTimeZoneDifference()));
            Log.i("Time zone", "after gmt +gettime=" + cal.getTime());
            date = cal.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formatter1.format(date);
    }



public static final int getTimeZoneDifference() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int gmtcurrentOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(currentTime);
        int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").getOffset(currentTime);
        int minuteDifference = (((gmtOffset - gmtcurrentOffset) / 1000) / 60);
        return minuteDifference;
    }
```

use 1st function and pass any date with yyy-mm-dd formate as a string. and that function will return gmt formate real date-time.

i already use it.
its working fine.i hope its useful to you.

Comment: I need to take the Timezone from General Variables and change the Time with respect to that timezone and not with the date with Calendar.getinstance() value.

Comment: @kumarsu np.you can take it from variable.you can use 2nd method.this is get difference between your variable timezone and GMT Timezone .

Comment: Should give an output for quick understand

Comment: @Mahmudul it is enough to understand which have knows timeZone knowledge.

Comment: Yes, But it is good practice to give code.. BTW, can you please tell me -1 in minuite given.